# working with unmanaged resources

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

I use a 3rd party library which is a wrapper around a native dll. the library contains a type `XImage`, `XImage` has some properties and a `IntPtr Data()` method. `XImage` also Implements `IDisposable` but I don't know if it is implemented correctly.

I get many `XImage`s from TCP connection and show them as a movie in a `PictureBox`.

I used to convert 'XImage' to `System.Drawing.Image` and view them in a `PictureBox` but I got `AccessViolationException`.

So I made a wrapper around `XImage` called `Frame`.

```
public class Frame : IDisposable
{
  public uint size { get; private set; }
  private Image image;
  public XImage XImage { get; set; }
  public Image Image { get { return image ?? (image = GetBitmap(this.XImage)); } }
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }

   public Frame(XImage xImage)
  {
    this.XImage = xImage;
    this.size = XImage.ImageBufferSize();
    GC.AddMemoryPressure(size);
  }


  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  ~Frame()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing)
    {
      try
      {
        image.Dispose();
      }
      catch { }
      finally
      {
        image = null;
      }
      try
      {
        MImage.Dispose();
      }
      catch { }
      finally { XImage = null; }
    }
    GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(size);
  }
}
```

and by handling references to `Frame` I solved the `AccessViolationException`.
now I have another Issue, when I run the program from visual studio (F5 - Start Debugging) everything is okay, but when I run it from the `.exe` file or (ctrl + F5 - Start without debugging) the memory usage is growing larger and larger until I get `OutOfMemoryException`.(Biuld Configuration: Release - X86). what should I do ?

**---- EDIT ----**

I found that `GC.AddMemoryPressure` or `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure` just makes the garbage collection to run more often and, my problem is now that I have small objects that have a handle to large unmanaged memory, and GC is not collecting these small objects.

**---- EDIT ----**
calling `GC.Collect` will solve the problem during run-time, I set up a timer and call `GC.Collect` periodically, but it makes the application freeze for a short period, so I don't want to use this approach.

Comment: You didn't solve it, you just hid it by catching all exceptions.  Getting a problem later is inevitable.  Ditch a library that gives you problems like this.

Comment: You're just swallowing all the exceptions in your `Dispose()` method. Chances are the `XImage` didn't actually dispose successfully.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think the library is okay. I set a timer and call GC.Collect() every 30 second and solve `OutOfMemoryException` but this is not a good approach. why running under debugger differs from running without debugger?

Comment: @angelsl: I checked single instance of `XImage` and it disposed correctly

Comment: So no `Exception`s at all? Perhaps something is taking up so much CPU time that the GC never gets a chance to run, which is why forcing a GC.Collect fixes the OOME. Try checking that?

Comment: @angelsl: showing two movie at the same time takes about 30 percent of CPU usage.

Comment: core i5 540M, 2 core, double threaded, btw the application is written using multi-threading

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11226/discussion-between-junishiro-and-angelsl)

Comment: For as long as the images received are the same size and format, the library should reuse the same memory for every frame it receives (or 2 buffers at most). If it does, you shouldn't dispose of the XImages, if it does not, then you should write your own library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `GC` has limitations and may not work too well under very heavy pressure and for memory intense application. I have an application that does not do anything with unmanaged resources directly, all standard .NET components, and it can still choke on memory. It can use GBs of RAM but not because of enormous memory requirements but because big objects are created and destroyed relatively quickly and apparently not collected too often. Application has no memory leaks as it is all freed when collection is forced. It looks like `GC` is not always able to collect unused objects on time i.e. before `OutOfMemoryException`. It waits to find the best moment but before it makes up its mind it is too late. When I periodically force the collection, application runs with no problems.

It is worth mentioning that `OutOfMemoryException` does not always mean that you're actually out of free memory. It can also mean there is no big enough contiguous memory chunk available. This may be the case especially when working with video and images. `GC` might think there is still plenty of memory free but it is too fragmented for your application. I am sure `GC` takes fragmentation into account but it is possible that it's not always getting it right.

If you are sure the library is not the problem, my advise is to experiment more with memory pressure methods ([AddMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx) and [RemoveMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.removememorypressure%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to help `GC` do its thing on time. It may solve your problems since you work with an unmanaged library that may be handling significant amounts of memory behind `GC`'s back. Alternatively do as you do with `GC.Collect`. Manual collection may not be ideal but I believe there are cases when it is justified. Of course do expect that manual collection of lots of objects may have an impact on your application performance.

**EDIT**

If manual collection introduces too much of a performance impact, try to use overloaded versions of `GC.Collect` that give you a bit more control.

Comment: I found that GC.AddMemoryPressure or GC.RemoveMemoryPressure just makes the garbage collection to run more often and, my problem is now that I have small objects that have a handle to large unmanaged memory, and GC is not collecting these small objects.

Comment: You shouldn't get OOM if you have objects that could be freed. But it's possible they are still referenced from somewhere, for example, the finalization queue. Besides, that does not seem to be relevant here.

Comment: I would think exactly the same - objects pending collection (even in finalization queue) should not lead to OOM. Unfortunately this sometimes happens in practice.

Comment: @MaciejDopieralski, large objects in finalization queue (or referenced by objects in finalization queue) could cause OOM, because objects in the queue can't be collected yet: their finalizer has to run first.

Comment: It is `GC` task to call finalizers so it's still `GC` to be blamed for OOM in this case.

Comment: You can blame who you want, but the GC can't influence how long does finalization of each object take.

Comment: Normal finalizers do not take a long time to run especially for standard .NET classes. Plus in the case in question `Dispose` is properly implemented and finalizers would be suppressed.